# Limiting rails to only responding to JSON and XML requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api

Is there a way to globally define a rails app to only serve json and xml and appropriately error on any other requests?

I'm thinking it's something along the lines of a before_filter and responds_to block in the ApplicationController but that's as far as my investigation has got me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just declare it at the class level on your controller, using [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html#method-i-respond_to). It will apply to all your controllers if you do it on `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :xml, :json
  …
end
```

Also read about [`ActionController::Responder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) class for more options.

Comment: I thought that but would i have to do additional work to render errors if other requests were made? I'd also wondered if rack would be a better place for this.

Comment: Strike that - works great :) Still wonder if rack would be better. Time to dig.

Comment: This made zero difference for me.  It only mattered what respond_to stuff I had to within my controller's actions.

Answer (score 3):

To make json response on errors, just add the following code to your application_controller:

```
rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_error
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_not_found
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_not_found
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :render_not_found
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_not_found

private

def render_not_found(exception)
  # logger.info(exception) # for logging 
  respond_to do |format|
    render json: {:error => "404"}, status: 404
  end    
end

def render_error(exception)
  # logger.info(exception) # for logging
  respond_to do |format|
    render json: {:error => "500"}, status: 500
  end
end

public

def some_public_func
 #do sthg
end
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this, `rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError` no longer works in Rails >= 3.0. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/671 and [part 3 of this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/) for more information.